# A minor detail in proofs in Groups Theory

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $A, B$ are subgroups of $G$. Let $N$ be a normal group such that $N \leq A$ and $N \leq B$.

Let $b_1, b_2 \in B$ and $a \in A$.

Suppose we have $b_2^{-1}b_1 \in aN \subset A$.

My question is: from here how can we conclude that $b_1A=b_2A$?

Here I can only see that $b_1 \in b_2A$

Thank you!

Comment: How are $a$, $b_1$ and $b_2$ chosen?

Comment: Sorry, I just added more details now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b_2^{-1}b_1\in A$, then multiply by $b_2$ on the left: $b_1\in b_2A$. Hence $b_1A\subseteq b_2A$. Then since $A$ is a subgroup, $b_1^{-1}b_2=(b_2^{-1}b_1)^{-1}\in A$, so $b_2A\subseteq b_1A$, QED.

Comment: But the OP is assuming that $b_2^{-1}b_1\in A$.  Granted, I'm not sure what role $N$ plays in the OP's question.

Comment: @lulu: What does OP assume?

Comment: Just quoting: "Suppose we have $b_2^{-1}b_1 \in aN \subset A$."  Ignoring the bit about $N$, that gives us  $b_2^{-1}b_1 \in  A$.

Comment: Ah, I did not notice that. It changes the answer.

Comment: Yes.  though, as I say, it seems to make $N$ entirely irrelevant, so something seems off.

Comment: Sorry, this question came from part of a proof.  In the original statement, $N$ is assumed to be normal, so I just put it there. Basically, it's the end of showing injectivity of (3) here https://linearalgebras.com/solution-abstract-algebra-exercise-3-3-2.html

Comment: I have fixed the answer.